# Modal dialog not always on top of an undecorated JFrame when another JFrame is visible

Tags: java, linux, swing, jframe, modal-dialog

I have a weird problem with modal dialogs **and** undecorated `JFrame`.

If I create a main undecorated `JFrame` then I display a modal dialog thanks to the `JOptionPane`, everything goes well. The modal dialog stays always on top and I can't click on the main fame.

But, if create another `JFrame` (or another `JDialog`), the modal dialog still prevent me to interact with the main frame, but now the modal dialog is not always on top and go underneath the main frame when I click on it.

This problem doesn't happen:

- if the main frame is decorated
- or if the second frame is not visible

EDIT

I use `jdk1.7.0.0_09` on `Linux Sus`e.But I have the same result with `jre 1.6.0_32`

The code I used to test:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    // creates main frame and set visible to true
    final JFrame mainFrame = new JFrame();
    mainFrame.setUndecorated(true); // if I comment this line, everything goes well
    mainFrame.add((new JPanel()).add(new JButton("OK")));
    mainFrame.setSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
    mainFrame.setVisible(true);
    // creates a dialog and set visible to true
    JFrame anotherFrame = new JFrame();
    anotherFrame.setVisible(true); // or if I comment this line, everything goes well too
    // display a modal dialog
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(mainFrame, "A message");
}
```

Comment: Does the problem still occurs if you stop violating the EDT and call everything in `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` or `EventQueue.invokeLater`?

Comment: See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9554657/418556)

Answer (score 4):

> But, if create another JFrame (or another JDialog), the modal dialog
>   still prevent me to interact with the main frame, but now the modal
>   dialog is not always on top and go underneath the main frame when I
>   click on it.

- not true at all, both are not accesible untill JOptioPane is visible
- JOptionPane or JDialod.setModal(true) block mouse or key events to the alll windows invoked from currnet JVM
- there must be something else that isn't clear from your question, rest of code, minor could be Java version and Native OS

[image]

code for Java6 (winxp), works for me on Win7 / Java7(x.x_011)

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Main {

   private JFrame mainFrame = new JFrame();
   private JFrame anotherFrame = new JFrame();

    public Main() {
        mainFrame.setUndecorated(true);
        mainFrame.add((new JPanel()).add(new JButton("OK")));
        mainFrame.setSize(new Dimension(100, 60));
        mainFrame.setVisible(true);
        mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        anotherFrame.setVisible(true);
        anotherFrame.setLocation(110, 0);
        anotherFrame.setSize(new Dimension(100, 60));
        anotherFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(mainFrame, "A message");
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
       java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                Main main = new Main();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I use your code and I have always the behavior I described previously. If I click on the main frame the dialog goes underneath. I use jdk1.7.0.0_09 on Linux Suse.But I have the same result with jre 1.6.0_32

Comment: there are a few **nix/Linux users, I edited tags and add Java & Native OS to the question body, have to wait

Comment: Ok, thx. I made some tests. The problem seems to come from the Window Manager. With the Metacity I have the problem, but I haven't with Kwin. Don't know why...